# FactomineR how to change the text of in HCPC plot?

Tags: r, graphics, legend, hierarchical-clustering

Using HCPC, a function of FactoMineR for clustering, how can we change the text legend of an HCPC plot? Exactly, how to change "cluster 1","cluster 2" etc. with a text vector we specified (legend.txt as a vector)
Here the code which works

```
cai<-PCA(iris[,-5]) 
res.hcpc2 <- HCPC(pcai, graph = FALSE)
plot(res.hcpc2, choice = "3D.map", title= "mapping site clusters "))
```

[image]
If we try to change the legend

```
leg.txt <- c("SE", "VE", "VI") 
plot(res.hcpc2, choice = "3D.map", title= "mapping site clusters ", legend=leg.txt))
```

we get an error message "legend is not a graphical parameter", and the text of the legend is not changed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should mention in your question that `HCPC` is a function in the `FactoMineR` package. Looking at the manual page for `plot.HCPC` in the package I do not see any way to modify or suppress the default legend, but you should contact the package maintainer, `maintainer("FactoMineR")`, to be sure. You can use a kludge to overwrite the default legend as follows:

```
 legend("topleft", c("SE", "VE", "VI"), bg="white", pch=16, col=1:3,
      text.col=1:3, text.width=1.1, cex=.8)
```

The problem is that the box is larger than it needs to be. This version will just print the legend without a box:

```
legend("topleft", c("SE", "VE", "VI"), bg="white", pch=16, col=1:3,
     text.col=1:3, text.width=1.3, cex=.8, box.col="white", xpd=NA)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72958698/adding-group-information-to-3d-plot-in-factoextra I have pretty much similar question is there way to add metadata information here ?